# VBA Match function not working with large numbers

Tags: excel, vba

I made a custom type, which I called Run, and one of its values is called RunMOA. It stores a String, which is always a 12-digit number. I have an array of these Runs, each with a different MOA. I also have a sheet that has a column of all possible MOAs, and I'm trying to loop through the array of Runs and get the row number of that Run's respective MOA (for finding other data in that sheet).

Strangely, this is working for a bunch of the MOAs, but not for specific ones. I did some playing around, and it almost seems to be an error caused by rounding or something. For example, these MOAs are being found in the column:

200630031111, 200630021593, 200630021593,

but these ones aren't:

200000000443, 200000000603, 200000000444.

Here's the code that loops through the values (NumRuns is the length of the Runs array):

```
Dim i As Integer
For i = 0 To NumRuns - 1

    GetRun i, n, Schedule, SKUs

Next i
```

Here's the line that's supposed to store the row number in a variable:

```
Row = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(Val(Runs(i).RunMOA), Worksheets("Sheet1").Range(Cells(2, 1), Cells(n, 1))) - 1
```

Does this function have a problem when numbers are too big? It's only giving me trouble when there are a lot of zeros in a row, and I can't find an explanation for that. And I checked and double checked that these MOAs are in the column, so it's not an issue of them being missing.

Comment: I'm not sure how your loop is working but did you make sure that `i` and `n` ever make it to the value where it would find a match? For example if your cell 70500 contains the match, but you only loop until n = 65000 then it won't even look for it, Please post your loop as well

Comment: What type is `Row` declared as? See [Data-Types-and Limits](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/vba/3418/data-types-and-limits)

Comment: Also [Avoid re-purposing the names of Properties or Methods as your variables](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/excel-vba/drafts/43318#).

Comment: @DavidG: those variables seem to be working alright. I'll update the post with the code from that loop, but I just checked the values in debug mode, and they're correct

Comment: @Jeeped Row is declared as an Integer

Comment: What is the code for `GetRun`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are currently using an approximate match for the [MATCH function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/match-function-0600e189-9f3c-4e4f-98c1-943a0eb427ca) and data must be sorted in an ascending order to use the default *match_type* value of 1. Use an exact match with a *match_type* of 0.

```
Row = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(Val(Runs(i).RunMOA), Worksheets("Sheet1").Range(Cells(2, 1), Cells(n, 1)), 0) - 1
```

Btw, this would be better as,

```
dim rw as variant
rw = Application.Match(Val(Runs(i).RunMOA), Worksheets("Sheet1").Range(Cells(2, 1), Cells(n, 1)), 0)
if not IsError(rw) then
    rw = rw - 1
    'more operational code here
else
    ' match failed - deal with error
end if
```

Comment: I can't believe I missed that, I thought it would behave that way without the optional parameter. That seemed to fix it! Thanks so much

Comment: Ryan - double check your maths as well. You are subtracting 1 but to get the actual row on the worksheet, you should be adding 1. The MATCH is returning the *position within row 2 to whatever* so a 1 means row 2 on the worksheet.